# Parcel project filesize huge

Tags: bootstrap-5, filesize, parcel

Okay I'm building a website and yes I'm a graphic designer trying to code :)

So I have a parcel 2 bootstrap 5.3 project with a video around 8 gb. So that takes up some space. But my hole project file size is 68gb which is insane. My dist and src folder are each 8.8gb, node modules 350mb - so I don't understant why the project filesize is 68gb...

I think maybe I need to clear some Parcel cache or something? Or maybe I have done something wrong in the setup - can anyone point me in the right direction on how to solve this. Thank you.

I'm not sure what to share cause I don't understand what's causing the problem but here is my Package.json looks like this. I have tried 2 times to setup new projects and import my code but same problem...

```
`{
  "name": "umswebsite",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel serve src/index.html --public-url / --dist-dir dist --open",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html",
    "prebuild": "rm -rf dist",
    "browserslist": "> 0.5%, last 2 versions, not dead"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/transformer-sass": "^2.9.3",
    "parcel": "^2.9.3",
    "video.js": "^8.5.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
    "jquery": "^3.7.1",
    "jquery-ui-dist": "^1.13.2"
  }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok had to add `.parcel-cache` which clears it:

```
  "prebuild": "rm -rf dist .parcel-cache",
```